# Using python to define & return function

Tags: python, function, return

I apologize for the beginner question but I’ve tried multiple iterations and various spacing and syntax changes for the past few hours with no luck.

I am trying to define a simple function to give me the max value of a specific column. I want to return the value of the country that has the highest number of gold medals from an Olympic dataset found on Wikipedia.

The data frame (df) has already been defined and the dataset has already been organized in the first step.

So my second step of code ends up looking something like this:

```
def function_one():
    df.(“Gold”).idxmax()

    return df.(“Gold”).idxmax()

function_one()
```

I get an error that “df” is not defined but it’s defined previously in the first part of the Jupyter notebook.

I’ll add the logo and some other info in here as well.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Many thanks!

Comment: I would rather use `df["Gold"].idxmax()`

Comment: You seem to have a local vs global issue.  Show the first cell.  Best to rewrite and avoid using globals.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that a function can access an object then pass it as an argument:

```
def max_gold_idx(dataframe):
    return dataframe["Gold"].idxmax()

max_gold_idx(df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**. You need to pass the df to the function (This is the current error being raised):

```
def function_one(df):
    return df.("Gold").idxmax()

function_one(df)
```

**Step 2**. Your next issue will be syntax. To isolate a column in a `dataframe` use `[]`:

```
def function_one(df):
    return df[“Gold”].idxmax()

function_one(df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)